# Using two Flexbox in a Table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn how to use flex-box and have hit a road block. I cant seem to fix the problem.
I am trying the "Flex-box Test" side to be responsive with it contents but would like the "Employee of the week" side to have a fix position but also its contents to be flexible. But when I resize it, I would like the "Employee of the week" side to be always start at the top right.

Is there a fix to this?
Is there any tutorial of how to structure html and CSS code well?
Or should I use tables instead?

```css
.body {
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.flexbox-container-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: gray;
  background-color: black;
}

.flexbox-container-column {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: gray;
  background-color: black;
}

.flexbox-item {
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}

.flexbox-item1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.flexbox-item2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.flexbox-item3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.textalignment {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <h1 class="textalignment">FLEX Box Test</h1>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h1 class="textalignment">EMPLOYEE OF THE WEEK</h1>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="flexbox-container-flex">
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item1"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item2"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item3"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item1"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item2"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item3"></div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="flexbox-container-column">
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item1"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item2"></div>
            <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item3"></div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Honestly, my first thought when I read your title was "the answer is ... don't do it!" ;-)  Could you maybe speak to *why* you want to use the very modern CSS technology of flexboxes with the early 2000's idea of using tables for layout (vs. using flexboxes for everything, or using CSS Grid, or using floats inside the table, or ...)?  I'm *not* saying what you're doing is wrong ... I'm just trying to understand the desire to mix old and new approaches in this way.  I wouldn't want to provide an answer of "just use a flexbox instead of your table" if you have a good reason to use a table.

Comment: There is no special reason. It is for experiment purposes. Im still learning Html and CSS.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well look, in tech and in web development, there are often many ways to "skin the cat", and there isn't always a "right" one.  In this case, while I'd imagine you *could* (probably) get the layout you desire with tables and flexboxes ... I imagine you'd be able to solve this on your own fairly easily if you just use a flexbox `div` instead of a table, because then everything will be "playing by the same rules".  But again, I'm not saying that approach is "right" so much as "more modern" and "probably easier for you".

Comment: Using a table here is definitely wrong. Use a `<table>` only if you show any tabular data. You don't show any tabular data here so get rid of the table. Table were only used for layouts in the last century when there were no other ways to do this.